How does serde export both a trait and a derive macro with the same name?
I am trying to implement a trait Foo in a foo crate as well an identically named #[derive] proc-macro in an associated crate foo-macros.
The intent is to have something like serde::Deserialize which is both a trait and a derive macro.
To make things more convenient for the users, I wanted to re-export the derive macros of my foo-macros crate into my foo crate, again, just like serde does.
However, I am facing this error when I attempt to do that:
error[E0252]: the name `Foo` is defined multiple times

Here is the sample of code that triggers this:
//! My `foo` crate `lib.rs`.

mod foo;

pub use foo::Foo;

#[cfg(feature = "derive")]
extern crate foo_macros;

#[cfg(feature = "derive")]
pub use foo_macros::Foo;

I am at loss understanding why this works in serde but not in my case. What am I missing?

Is foo-macros defined as a proc-macro crate?

@ChayimFriedman Yes it is. The macros are otherwise working perfectly fine. It's really just this reimport logic that I am failing to implement.

You, and serde, can have a derive macro with the same name as a trait because derive macros occupy a different namespace from traits.

Namespaces allow the occurrence of a name in one namespace to not conflict with the same name in another namespace.

If Rust saw foo::Foo as a trait and foo_macros::Foo as a macro, it wouldn't complain about multiple definitions of the name Foo.
The issue is most likely that the Rust compiler doesn't see foo_macros::Foo as a macro because there is some error preventing foo_macros from parsing, compiling, or being imported as a source of procedural macros.

As already noted by Chayim Friedman in a comment on your post, there are certain essential steps to make a procedural macro such as a derive macro.
Try adding the #[macro_use] attribute:

#[cfg(feature = "derive")]
#[macro_use]
extern crate foo_macros;


Alternatively, remove extern crate foo_macros; (treating it as a normal Cargo.toml dependency), after upgrading to Rust edition 2018 or higher.

It's also possible that foo::Foo doesn't resolve to a trait, such as due to an import path error.
If #[macro_use] doesn't work and you don't see any issue with your macro or trait, consider adding them (and the full Rust compiler output) to your post, to reach a minimum reproducible example.
